# Marshal Bitmap from another process

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling, unsafe, abbyy

I've got a bitmap handle that I get from another process. Unfortunately I can't change code in this process, because it's an third party SDK (Abbyy Finereader SDK).

I create a FRDocument and try to get the bitmap handle with GetPicture from Abbyy Image object like this:

```
        FRDocument doc = engine.CreateFRDocumentFromImage(PATH_TO_SAMPLE_BITMAP);
        FRPage page = doc.Pages[0];

        FREngine.Image colorImage = page.ImageDocument.ColorImage;
        long hbitmap = colorImage.GetPicture(null, 0);

        IntPtr bitmapPtr = new IntPtr(hbitmap);

        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(bitmapPtr);
```

Now I want to get a Bitmap with `Bitmap.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);` but Bitmap class throws an exception with message "A generic error occured in GDI+". No InnerException is provided. The handle seems to be correct.

In the SDK description is described that it should work with marshalling but no more information or code examples are provided. I've googled around much, but I'm not an expert for marshalling and this topic seems to be really complex.

Has anyone an idea how I can get a bitmap from the handle that was created in another process? 
I hope my question was understandable.

UPDATE:

I did some research and found in the Abbyy SDK description that the bitmap provided from GetPicture() is created with CreateDIBSection and passed under clients ownership. But I don't know how to get a bitmap that was created with this (native) method in C#.

Comment: I feel your pain. That particular error message is thrown for a gigantic number of reasons. To list a few (and hopefully help): Image is too big. Image is disposed. Image has a strange pixel format. Your process is violating a security permission.

Comment: Also.. can you show us how you're setting the value of the `hBitmap` variable?

Comment: Thx for your answer. I guess the case that the image is too big or disposed can be excluded, because if I load the third party SDK In Process (which I can't use in productive environment because it blocks my GUI) the Bitmap is created without problems. I think your hint with process security permissions may be correct, but I don't really know how to fix this.

Comment: Updated my answer. I get the hBitmap from Abbyy Finereader SDK.

Comment: Without access to their API (which appears to be not freely available after a simple Google search), I don't think anyone would be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that you would like to perform some external pre-processing of your image before recognizing it with the FineReader Engine?
In this case the scenario may be the following:

```
// Create document
FREngine.FRDocument document = engineLoader.Engine.CreateFRDocument();
document.AddImageFile( imagePath, null, null );
// . . .
FREngine.ImageDocument imageDoc = document.Pages[pageNumber].ImageDocument;
IntPtr hBitmap = ( IntPtr )( imageDoc.ColorImage.GetPicture( null, 0 ) );
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.FromHbitmap( hBitmap );
// Perform manipulations with Bitmap object
// . . .
document.Close();
document = engineLoader.Engine.CreateFRDocument();

int manipulatedHBitmap = ( int )( bitmap.GetHbitmap() );
FREngine.ImageDocument imageDocument = engineLoader.Engine.OpenBitmapImage( manipulatedHBitmap, resolution );
document.AddImage( imageDocument );
// Perform image processing with the FineReader Engine
// . . .
```

Please pay your attention to the fact that the correct resolution value should be passed to the OpenBitmapImage() method as the incorrect resolution value may decrease recognition quality. For example, you could store the resolution value of your initial image using the imageDoc.ColorImage.XResolution property.

If you have further questions, please contact sdk_support@abbyy.com.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Vitalik. Yes, you understood me fully correct. I already tried it this way. I get an exception in System.Drawing when I get to Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.FromHbitmap( hBitmap );. The exception only says "A generic error occured in GDI+" like described above. I used exactly your code. I use the OutprocEngineLoader.